# Would it be possible to redirect a sub domain to another virtual server?

Tags: web-services

A friend of mine has two virtual servers with two different web apps running on both but wants to resolve his subdomain address (i.e. www.subdomain.domain.com) to the second virtual server. Unfortunately, he has bought these servers with a provider (1&1), so I know it wont be easy. I imagine they (server providers) will have a BIND/DNS server and should be able to allow this, however I just want to know if it's possible to achieve this without having to get them to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running apache you might be able to do it with virtual hosts:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/